# The probability that the lightbulb will function for more than 2000 days, given that it is still functional after 500 days

Tags: probability

The lifetime of a lightbulb can be modeled with an exponential random variable with an expected lifetime of 1000 days.

(b) Find the probability that the lightbulb will function for more than 2000 days, given that it is still functional after 500 days.

So if X is the lifetime of a lightbulb, then $X\sim Exp(\frac{1}{1000})$. Any Ideas How to find the conditional probability?

Comment: Use memorylessness of exponential r.v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to compute $\mathbb{P}(X>2000|X>500)$, where $X$ is the R.V. denoting the lifetime of the bulb. Since $X \sim exp(\lambda)$, $\mathbb{P}(X>x)= e^{-\lambda x}$, with $\lambda = 1/1000$.

$\mathbb{P}(X>2000|X>500) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>2000,X>500)}{\mathbb{P}(X>500)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>2000)}{\mathbb{P}(X>500)} = \frac{e^{-2000\lambda}}{e^{-500\lambda}} = e^{-1500\lambda} = e^{-1500/1000} = 0.2231$.

This is a good illustration of the "memoryless" property of an exponential random variable.